# Reportviewer and report are in different projects in the same solution. How do I attach the report to the viewer

Tags: c#, winforms, reporting-services, report, report-viewer2012

I have a forms application and it has a reportviewer in it.  In the same solution, but different project, I have a report (rdl).  I would like to use the report in the different project as the report displayed to the reportviewer.  This is opposed to using a report that is deployed to a server.

I originally had this report deployed to a local reporting server.  I was using that deployment to display to the reportviewer.  However, I would like to use a local one, so that I can upload this to a Mercurial repository with the db, report and form all included.

Answer (score 0):

Set your report's `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy Always` then add its path to your `ReportViewer`:

```
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "yourReportFileName.rdlc";
```

Comment: ok, I found the LocalReport and the ReportPath property under it in the property panel.  However when I click on the Rdl file there are only two properties "File Name" and "Full Path".  

I went to projects->report projects and set the output path to "..\myMainProject\bin\Debug", but that didn't work either.  Note I tried to go up a level first, to leave the Report Project.  It didn't work though

Comment: You can refer to `Rdlc` file if it's in/under your solution. Not sure why it don't work, maybe yours is `Rdl` cause it :)