# How can we get around a ReportViewer's inability to use reports from another project?

Tags: c#, rdlc, reportviewer, n-tier-architecture

I am currently working on a college C# project where I am required to apply N-Tier Architecture with 5 Layers:

- Data Access
- SQL Layer
- Business Layer
- Desktop Front End
- Web Front End

One of the requirements of the project is to display reports.

I chose to use ReportViewer and RDLC reports to accomplish this. My choice has been working fine until I reached the final iteration of the project.

Before this iteration, I only had to generate reports from the Desktop application and the RDLC report was inside my Desktop application project. Now I need to generate the report on a ASP.Net WebForm.

Since the report needs to be accessed by 2 different projects, I thought all I had to do was move the RDLC report up a layer, to my Business Layer (probably should have been there anyways, oops). Of course, I ran into problems. It's never that easy, is it?

After some searching I found 2 particular useful posts:

1. [Reportviewer and report are in different projects in the same solution. How do I attach the report to the viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31550965/reportviewer-and-report-are-in-different-projects-in-the-same-solution-how-do-i)
2. https://forum.inductiveautomation.com/t/displaying-a-report-over-multiple-projects/12825

The first post told me all that I would need to do is set the `Copy to Output Directory` of my RDLC file to `Copy always` and then set the `ReportViewer.LocalReport.ReportPath` to the rdlc's file name with the extension (`"example.rdlc"`).

Unfortunately, this answer never worked for both me and the OP. Why it didn't work was explained in the second post:

> A report viewer cannot view a report from another project, although this may make a good feature request. - [adam.morales](https://forum.inductiveautomation.com/t/displaying-a-report-over-multiple-projects/12825/2)

I then tried something a little different. Instead of accessing the report with `ReportPath` from a different project, why don't I create a property in my business layer that will return a `LocalReport` that already has the report definition? 
Unfortunately, `ReportViewer.LocalReport` is read only. Even if it was writable, I would not be surprised if it didn't solve the issue; because, `ReportPath` is a string and the issue probably occurs when the `LocalReport` attempts to render.

This poses a very big problem for me. There is not enough time to completely redo the Reports and I don't want to have to resort to have 2 different RDLC files, 1 for each front end project; because, that's bad design.

To be completely clear on my needs:

- I need to be able to access a RDLC report from 2 different projects
- I must follow N-Tier Architecture and keep code reusable

So, that's why I ask, what kind of work-around could I possibly try to remedy this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the best I could find is embedding a PDF into the WinForms. This seems to require third-party DLLs, something I've been trying to avoid; because, it's a college project.

While this is not tested yet...
The `LocalReport.Render` method can generate a PDF (among a variety of things) as an `Byte[]`. If I use the `Render` method inside my Business Layer; then, I would expect it work since `LocalReport` would do its own thing while in the same project as the RDLC file and therefor work.

After that I should be able to simply return the generated report and use it where ever I want.

Unfortunately, I don't want to go through the complexity of adding third-party dlls to the college project so I'm going to simply duplicate the RDLC files... Hate the solution; but, it is what it is.